# seabornのdistplotで表示したグラフ上のピンの位置が知りたい

Tags: python, pandas

seabornのdistplotで表示したグラフについて，
個々のビンの位置と高さが知りたいのですが方法はないでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

以下のリンクを参考にコードを書いてみました、高さについてはこれで取得できると思います。
[Get data points from Seaborn distplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37374983/get-data-points-from-seaborn-distplot)

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from pprint import pprint
sns.set()
np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.rand(100)
pprint([h.get_height() for h in sns.distplot(x).patches])
"""
>> [1.2707405677074517,
    0.8132739633327691,
    1.0674220768742593,
    1.0674220768742597,
    0.8641035860410673]
"""
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ところで上記のリンクですが
Google検索に**seaborn displot bin get height**のように打つと上から４番目にのっていました。本家のstackoverflowは蓄積された知識量が多いので質問する前に、質問者様自ら調べてもらえますとここで聞くよりもすぐ解決できるかもしれません。